nvme SSD is missing in /dev/disk/by-path on the ubuntu 22.04

issue : Missing NVME disk in the /dev/disk/by-path/

OS ver : Ubuntu 22.04 ( 5.15.0-78-generic )

systemd version : 249.11-0ubuntu3.12

nvme disk vendor : Samsung PM1733a RI 1.9TB/3.8TB


The nvme disk detected in the /dev/disk/by-id/ and everything is working properly but it's not listed in the /dev/disk/by-path/
The symptom is exactly the same as the bug below(it's from redhat)
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2031810 (Bug 2031810 - Symlinks to NVMe drives are missing in /dev/disk/by-path)
Let me know the solution.

your kernel is a bit old. uname -r 5.15.0-105-generic
